# Split Pelican articles into multiple pages

Tags: python, pelican

I have a few longer articles in my blog and would like to split them somehow into multiple pages, e.g. through inserting manual page breaks.

Is there any plugin for this or any default template mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two related plugins in the [Pelican Plugins](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins) repository:

- [Series](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/series)
- [Sub-parts](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/sub_parts)

I imagine you will find that one — or both in conjunction — will suit your needs.